# Google Sign-in using Angular app with a Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-in into my Angular 8 app which has a REST backend in Node.js+Express.js, I'm not able to find a usefull library, can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) for this purpose which is very easy to implement and understand. Either this [Google oauth2 nodejs library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) describes the steps to implement the Google Auth in a node.js environment.